# Assigning parse key value to a string

Tags: android, parse-platform

my ParseObject in the database called "Ads" and it has two keys title and price.
how can i assign the value of the key title in the String "t"
and the value of price in the String "p"?

here is my code

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    String t;
    String p;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ads");
        query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // object will be your game score
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ParseObject is a local representation of data that can be saved and retrieved from the Parse cloud.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    String t;
    String p;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ads");
        query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
             public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                 if (e == null) {
                     t = object.getString("ColumnName")
                     p = object.getString("ColumnName")
                 } else {
                     //objectRetrievalFailed
                 }
             }
        });
    }
}
```